# Get AutoIncrement ID and insert into Foreign Key Table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have 3 tables `User`, `Profile` and `ProfilePicture`. `Profile` and `ProfilePicture` have a foreign key relation with `User` table. What I want to do here is whenever I insert data into the `User` table through web application their `AutoGeneratedID` get and inserted into `Profile` and `ProfilePicture` tables.

```
CREATE TABLE User 
(
    UserId INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    Username VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    Password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`UserId`), 
    UNIQUE INDEX `UserIdId_UNIQUE` (`UserId` ASC)
); 

CREATE TABLE Profile 
( 
    UserId INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    Firstname VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    Lastname VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES User (UserId) 
)

CREATE TABLE ProfilePicture 
( 
    UserId INT(11) NOT NULL, 
    Picture image NULL, 
    insertdate date NULL,

    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES User (UserId) 
)
```

I know I have to use a trigger but I don't understand how to do this.

Comment: use ouput and  inserted

Comment: Drop the backticks ( ` )  - those are *not* necessary in SQL Server / T-SQL ...

Comment: You tagged this with sql server but the syntax looks like mysql. You have backticks and AUTO_INCREMENT. Which DBMS are you actually using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am supposing that you are doing this using stored procedure or raw queries. This thing can be achieved by using **OUTPUT** clause.

1. Define a local table with column Id

   ```
   DECLARE @OutputTbl TABLE (ID INT)
   ```
2. Now when you save the User then insert the new gnerated id into @OutputTbl

   ```
   INSERT INTO User (Username, Password)
   OUTPUT INSERTED.UserId INTO @OutputTbl(ID)
   VALUES ('name', 'password')
   ```
3. Now when you need this id in Profile/ProfilePicture, get this id from local table

   ```
   insert into Profile ( 
   UserId , 
   Firstname, 
   Lastname) Values ((Select ID from @OutputTbl),'fName','lName')
   ```

Comment: OUTPUT Inserted.userId into @OutputTbl(ID) What is `@OutputTbl(ID)` i have to create table

Comment: no, you don't need to create table it's just Table-valued parameters, it will be in memory

Comment: @Sri for more on table variable please follow http://odetocode.com/articles/365.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as below :

```
CREATE TABLE #tempUser(
    UserId INT,
    ShopRef INT
)


INSERT INTO [User] (UserPassword,Name,MobileNo,Gender,Dob,Country,State,City,StreetAddress
                    ,ZipCode,IsActive
                    ,CreatedDate,ModifiedBy,CreatedBy,IsAdmin,EmailOtp,UserImage,Rating
                    ,ContactNo)
            OUTPUT inserted.UserId, inserted.EmailOtp INTO #tempUser
            SELECT  'NA', [Name], [MobileNo], '-','1900-01-01',[Country],[State],[City],[StreetAddress],    
                    [ZipCode], 1
                    ,@Date,@UserId,@UserId,0,ID,'NA',0
                    ,'NA'
            FROM #temp WHERE Status ='SUCCESS'
```

If you are executing these inserts in the same SP then you can use, make sure UserId is an Identity Column :

```
SET @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: i have to create this table `#tempUser` so where i have to create. and can i use your code exactly in my stored procedure

Comment: Yes, you will have to create the #temp table.
No, you cannot use my code, this is just for reference. You need to modify according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

you can after insert into table, call SCOPE_IDENTITY() function, to get the latest 
identity inserted

for more informatin see:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE-IDENTITY-IDENT-C